# Mono.subscribe(consumer, errorConsumer, completeConsumer, subscriptionConsumer) does not invoke consumer and completeConsumer?

Tags: java, project-reactor

As subject, the 4th variant of `Mono.subscribe` does not seem to invoke the success consumer and complete consumer. It only invoke subscription consumer.

The code below failed

```
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(3);
    Mono.just(1).subscribe(i -> latch.countDown(), throwable -> {}, latch::countDown, s -> latch.countDown());
    boolean success = latch.await(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Assert.assertEquals(true, success);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the versions of `subscribe` with a `Consumer<Subscription>` are meant for you to drive the initial `request`. If you don't call `request(n)` on the subscription in the consumer, no data will be emitted and the `Mono` won't complete...

This works as expected:

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(3);
Mono.just(1).subscribe(
            i -> latch.countDown(),
            throwable -> {},
            latch::countDown,
            s -> {
                s.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
                latch.countDown();
            });
boolean success = latch.await(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Assert.assertEquals(true, success);
```

Comment: Thanks @SimonBaslé, but the method name has indicated that it is subscribing. So it is a little bit misleading that user has to manually request using the subscription passed there. At the javadoc does not give any clue about it.

Comment: I agree, this should be made clearer. This is mentioned in the parameter's description: "@param subscriptionConsumer the consumer to invoke on subscribe signal, to be used for the initial {@link Subscription#request(long) request}, or null for max request"